# How to deploy java class as a service in weblogic

Tags: java, email, weblogic, soa, bpel

All,

I have a java class which polls on a mailbox. I want deploy this class as a service in weblogic so that when the service is started it should continuously poll the mail box until the service is stopped. Its working as a standalone component, i want to deploy this as a service.

Thanks,

Ram

Comment: Did you google your question? There are hundreds of good examples already out there.... http://www.coderanch.com/t/566444/BEA-Weblogic/deploy-Java-Main-class-service http://shaoxiongyang.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-to-use-ejb-3-timer-in-weblogic-10.html